# Datatables jquery dynamically setting ajax url parameter

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, url, datatables

I'm using datatables and retrieving data via ajax from a database:

```
        ...
        deferRender: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "/api/tracks/classical",
            dataSrc: '',
            contentType: "application/json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Category" },
            { "data": "Title" },
         ...
```

When a menu option is selected I want to change the url to read a different set of data and reload the table:
eg
/api/tracks/**classical** will become
/api/tracks/**acoustic**

(This is effectively calling the same api with a different parameter.)

I tried setting the new url when the menu is clicked, and when debugging I can see it does call the new url, but then immediately calls the old one again and the table is redrawn the same.

```
 $('#menu-t-acoustic').click(function () {
       $('#mytable').ajax.url('/api/tracks/acoustic').load();
 });
```

So how can I achieve this with jquery/json/datatables?

I'm thinking that the url

```
    ajax: {
        url: "/api/tracks/classical"
```

should be able to use a variable instead of hard coded string but I don't know any syntax to do this - is it possible?

So... how should I set the ajax url dynamically - and how to I get datatables to reload with the new url?

Answer (score 0):

try calling `load` on instance variable returned by `datatables`.
something like

```
var yourdatatable = $('#mytable').DataTable( {
                     ....
                     ajax: {
                      url: "/api/tracks/classical",
                      dataSrc: '',
                      contentType: "application/json"
                     },
                     ....
                    });

yourdatatable.ajax.url('/api/tracks/acoustic').load();
```

Example from documentation.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "data.json"
} );

table.ajax.url( 'newData.json' ).load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to achieve the dynamic rendering you can use variables (i.e. `var apiToQuery`) and then add that onto the end of your api url:

```
$('.yourMenuButtons').click(function () {
    var apiToQuery = $(this).val();
    $('#mytable').ajax.url('/api/tracks/' + apiToQuery).load();
});
```

However to answer your question about it rendering the default ajax call, does that need to be hard-coded? I'm thinking you could leave the ajax call out of the initial table code, and then do that in a separate event handler:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#mytable').ajax.url('/api/tracks/defaultApiQuery').load();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create your DataTable, assign it to a variable:

```
var datatable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    datatable = $("#table").DataTable({
        ...
    });
});

function filterResults(filter) {
    datatable.ajax.url('/api/tracks/' + filter).load();
}
```

DataTables will take care of nicely appending its own parameters. Good luck!

Rather late, but I think this can help other folks...